# How do I store an output of a function into an array in Kotlin

Tags: arrays, function, kotlin, random

So for an assignment, I have to maker a program that generates 200 random numbers and then gets stored into the array and then called upon later.  so I thought about storing the function in an array like this

```
    fun main() {
    var randomValues = arrayOf( List(200) { Random.nextInt(0, 100) })
    println(randomValues)
}
```

and that didn't work I get this output
`[Ljava.util.List;@533ddba`. I'm not too accustomed to arrays so I'm not sure what to do. Sorry if this has been asked before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created an `Array<List<Int>>`. So it's an array containing a list of numbers. Remove the surrounding `arrayOf()` and change `List` to `Array`.

And to print the contents of a collection, use `joinToString()`, so `println(randomValues.joinToString())`.

Comment: Or, if it doesn't strictly need to be an array, just keep the `List` — they're more flexible and better behaved (e.g. have a sensible `toString()`, so you can print them out directly even without a `joinToString()`).